# What is the configuration for JMeter Setup

Tags: jmeter

We have requirement, Have to run with 8000 concurrent users with 3 seconds of duration. We are dealing with healthcare domain, For this scenario what is the machine configuration we need to set in JMeter test execution machine using Distributed Testing?

Comment: This is a really broad question that can be done in many ways. You could buy tons of small Raspberry Pi'es or simply have one really powerfull machine. https://www.degree53.com/blog/2017/july/how-we-did-load-testing-using-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 1):

We don't know. It depends on many factors like:

- Number of [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in your Test Plan
- Request and response size
- Number of [Pre Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions), Timers, etc.

The recommended actions are:

1. Make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Make sure to monitor the baseline health metrics on the machine where JMeter is running as if JMeter lacks essential resources like CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. - it will not be able to send requests fast enough hence you will not get accurate results. If you don't have a monitoring solution in place - you can consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
3. Start your test with 1 user and gradually increase the load until you reach 8000 concurrent users or resources consumption exceeds the reasonable threshold (say, 90% of maximum available capacity), whatever comes the first. If JMeter stars lacking resources and you haven't reached 8000 users - mention how many users were online using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener  - this is how many users you can simulate using particular this machine for particular this test. This should give you understanding how many machines you will need for the [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).

More information: [What’s the Max Number of Users You Can Test on JMeter?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter)